# Spring Security 3.1.3 @Autowired not Work when using WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring-security

Is spring security 3.1.3 have an issue @Autowired not work when using WebApplicationInitializer?

I get NullPointerException

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.x.y.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:29)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
package com.x.y.service.impl;

import com.x.y.dao.UserDao;
import com.x.y.dto.User;
import com.x.y.util.Assembler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {

        try{
            User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
            if(user == null) {
                System.out.println("[Login] username: " + username + " not found! back to login page");
                //throw new UsernameNotFoundException("[Login] User : " + username + " not found!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("[Login] username: " + username + " found! try to assemble user");
            }

            return assembler.assembleUser(user);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
package com.x.y.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.y")
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        /* read configuration */
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext acwac = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        acwac.setServletContext(servletContext);
        acwac.scan("com.x.y.config");
        acwac.refresh();

        /* dispatcher-servlet */
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic d = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(acwac));
        //d.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml");
        d.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        d.addMapping("/");

        /* context loader listiner */
        //servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(acwac));

    }

}
```

**WebAppConfig**

```
package com.x.y.config;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.y")
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class WebAppConfig {

    /* spring view configuration */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /* hibernate data source configuration */
    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource basicDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        /* data source properties */
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cadb_v1");
        dataSource.setUsername("cadb_admin");
        dataSource.setPassword("cadb_password");
        dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);

        return dataSource;
    }

    /* hibernate session factory configuration */
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        /* session factory bean properties */
        factoryBean.setDataSource(basicDataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.x.y.dto");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    /* hibernate transaction manager configuration */
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());

        return manager;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/view/error/access-denied.jsp">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/index?error=true" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.x.y.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        <!--    <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
        </security:authentication-provider>-->
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Please help me solve this problem, if you need more information let me know,

**Note: Just this @Autowired not work**

Regards,

**FYA**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you who give me "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful",
refers to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374904/spring-security-null-pointer-exception)

I just need add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

in **spring-security.xml** and it works now. Thanks, correct me if I'm wrong